# Notation question about Markov Chains: "the $j$th component of $\mathbf{s}Q^n$ is $P(X_n = j)$"

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I have a question about the following passage from my book (see screenshot below).

The book says: the $j$th component of $\mathbf{s}Q^n$ is $P(X_n = j)$

However shouldn't it say: the $j$th component of $\mathbf{s}Q^n$ is $P(X_n = j \mid \text{given $X_0$ has pmf $\mathbf{s}$})$

It seems to me that $\mathbf{s}Q^n$ does not yield the unconditional distribution of $X_n$ since it depends on how you set the pmf for $\mathbf{s}$.

To get the unconditional distribution $P(X_n =j)$ then you have to let $n \rightarrow \infty$ and you need your chain to settle on something (ergodic is the term maybe).

Can you help clarify my confusion? Thanks for your patience and help.

---

**Passage from book**

[image]

Comment: The condition is already given in the initial definition (in the proposition).  You're not wrong, but I don't think they need to add it again as an explicit condition on the probability.

Comment: @BrianTung Thanks for your help. Hmmm it just seems to me that the notation $P(X_n = j)$ should be reserved exclusively for the long run distribution of a Markov Chain regardless of the initial conditions. I'm learning all this for the first time so I'm just trying to shape this all up in my head...

Comment: I agree with BrianTung here, and disagree with your "Hmmm" thought.  A notation like $P(X_n=j)$ should be reserved precisely for the probability that $X_n$ equals $j$ according to the problem situation at hand, not to what you say.

Comment: @kimchilover Thanks that helps. You're right when I think about the unconditional probability of a coin landing heads I don't write $P(X=1 \mid \text{X is Bern(.5)})$ or something I just write $P(X = 1)$

Comment: @HJ_beginner: I can appreciate it that it seems more precise that way, but it can get verbose and hard to read if you include every last contextual assumption as a condition.  We don't typically write, for example, $P(\text{number of heads} = 5 \mid \text{coin remains fair throughout sequence})$ or some such.  For this reason (and others), usual mathematical exposition relies on a general acknowledgement of the problem's context.

Comment: @BrianTung Thanks for the explanation!